# Apache unable to write to NTFS automounted drive

Tags: partitioning, permissions, apache2, ntfs, elementary

I've a main ssd drive where os is installed
I have also a second drive (NTFS auto-mounted) where all www is hosted

All was working fine and Apache could load/write/etc. files into this NTFS partition

I had to erase/format my main drive and reinstall everything
**Now Apache can't write files into that partition**

I've restored from a backup the apache2 config, envvars, fstab, etc.

fstab:

```
UUID=587AA3687AA3421C  /media/datos   ntfs-3g   defaults,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0
```

apache2.conf:

```
<Directory /media/datos/html/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

apache2/envvars:

```
export APACHE_RUN_USER=kike
export APACHE_RUN_GROUP=kike
```

virtualhost.conf (it is a codeigniter 4 php app):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@localhost
    ServerName misite
    ServerAlias misite
    DocumentRoot /media/datos/html/misite/public   
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key    
    <Directory /media/datos/html/misite/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error_misite.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access_misite.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**PS:**
**- www-data is added into group kike (my user/group)**
**- PHP is installed as FPM service**

I've tried also this in fstab (w/o success):

```
UUID=587AA3687AA3421C  /media/datos   ntfs-3g   user,auto,exec,nodev,nosuid,async,rw,nls=utf8,umask=000,dmask=027,fmask=137,uid=1000,gid=1000,windows_names 0 0

UUID=587AA3687AA3421C /media/datos ntfs-3g uid=kike,gid=kike,nls=utf8,umask=007,windows_names 0 0
```

My user (kike) does not have problem in handling files/folders from this NTFS partition, but I wonder why this was working previously and now it doesn't

Thanks for any tip you can give me

Comment: Partly related: [How can web server access external-hdd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1220778)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While wondering what was different from previous installation, I noticed (then edited the question) that this time I installed php 8-1 fpm, so I begun searching about this and found the following

If I edit the following file

```
sudo nano /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

and then change the following variables to my username (instead www-data)

```
user = kike  
group = kike  
listen.owner = kike 
listen.group = kike
```

then save changes, restart apache2 and php8.1-fpm services

Then it works fine