# How to share a home-mounted cloud directory with a service user?

Tags: permissions, cloud

I have a pcloud cloud account, and all of my music lives there, it mounts a virtual drive to /home/myusername/pcloud and I'm looking specifically for the /home/myusername/pcloud/music folder.

As this folder is set up by pcloud by their app, there's no clear-cut way to move this folder.

Now enter jellyfin, I want it to serve files to various media players around the home. This is great and all, but it creates a different user. It creates a folder in my /home/ folder that it cant access, /home/myusername/Jellyfin Server Media, and *that is the only folder in my home folder it can access*.

As such, creating a /shared folder is not an option.

I've tried doing chmod to change the permissions to read & execute on the folders and files in my pcloud/music, but to no avail.

How do I give jellyfin permission to access the cloud music folder? Or alternatively, how do I make jellyfin run using my user?

Comment: What is the output of the `mount` (no parameters) command? Have you tried adding the jellyfin user to your user group or making the service run as your user?

Comment: I haven't added the jellyfin to my user group because I'd rather not have *all* my files accessible to jellyfin to share on the network. As for mounting, everything I see, both source & destination, are in the home directory.

Comment: I wondered about `mount` in case it was FUSE where `allow_other` would be necessary, but we can ignore that. Let's assume `pcloud` is not deleted or recreated automatically if overwritten. What happens if you: 1. Exit pcloud 2. `mv ~/pcloud ~/pcloud.bak` `3. ln -s ~/'Jellyfin Server Media' ~/pcloud` 4. Restart pcloud ?

Comment: I'm honestly afraid if I did that, it'd try to download all 4 terabytes of my cloud drive in the move. I'm more inclined to make Jellyfin the link, and hope whatever jellyfin did to access the folder was external to the folder. Checking the permissions, it doesn't look any different than other folders.

Comment: A bind mount might be what you need … So try `sudo mount --bind /home/myusername/pcloud/music  /home/myusername/Jellyfin\ Server\ Media`

Comment: @Raffa This gives me a "mount: [Jellyfin Directory] bind:[pcloud directory] failed" error with no other explanation

Comment: Are those apps installed via SNAP? … Please add the output of `snap list` to your question as well as `ls -ld` on both directories.

Comment: They are not installed via snaps, and my snap list is empty (this setup is on a new install).

Comment: Ok, please run `ls -ld` and `findmnt -T` on both directories and add that to your question and on `pcloud` not `pcloud/music`

Comment: Also I suspect `music` might not be actually a directory (may be a symlink) … So, try binding its parent i.e. `sudo mount --bind /home/myusername/pcloud /home/myusername/Jellyfin\ Server\ Media`

Comment: @Raffa That did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some services that allow accessing or serving local files publicly/remotely come pre-configured with or are allowed a limited scope of the filesystem hierarchy that they can access or can actually even see ... This is done as a second layer of data access security measures in addition to the other first layer of data access rights that are builtin those services in case they get compromised one way or another ... One example of those limited scope services is the Apache web server as discussed in [How can web server access external-hdd?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1220778/968501)

Therefore, altering permissions and directly trying to access or symbolically link to those files is simply not going to work as neither those files will be seen nor those symlinks will be followed by those processes.

So, you can **either**(don't do this) widen the scope of those services which defies the original purpose of protecting your data and might also break those services and cause them to stop working depending on what other security measures/checks are also builtin into them or imposed on them by the operating system's security policies ... **or**(recommended), you can bring those locations/files within the scope of those services by e.g. copying files, mounting filesystems or bind mounting directories and VFS mounts(already mounted filesystems) under whichever root directory already accessible to those services.

In your case, since you want that service to access a VFS mount, the easiest solution is to `mount --bind` Pcloud's mount point/directory at the configured root directory for Jellyfin like for example:

```
sudo mount --bind /home/myusername/pcloud /home/myusername/Jellyfin\ Server\ Media
```

... Now you should see the files under the new mount point but, you may still need to set permissions, access masks or ACLs on the new mount point and/or the files under it as needed.

**Notice** the above discussion is not specific to nor it's the only possible solution for Jellfin, but rather a general solution that should work for any similar case ... Also, I would encourage you to look into builtin options in Jellyfin's administration interface and read it's documentation to find out whether they recommend any other solutions specific to that service as they may already have some kind of implementation/add-on/plug-in that can fulfill your requirement as well.

Comment: Good job finding this answer! That would indeed work with the default setup. This was one of the options I considered, but I was blinded by the config on my machine. I set up systemd to unshare my user into a separate mount namespace, so I have to use a longer command instead of `sudo mount`. I didn't install either app, so I couldn't see the correct solution without confirming Jellyfin is or isn't in the right namespace or inherits properly.