# Why are files missing from directories when viewed from web?

Tags: permissions, apache2, files, directory

I am really puzzled by the behaviour of Apache 2 in displaying files contained in folders stored on my unix server. Until recently I had assumed that I could navigate through listings displayed on webpages, both locally or via the internet (using ngrok). But today I created some new files and directories to add to the listings, and even though the permissions and ownerships are identical, the new files won’t appear on the webpages.

I have been tearing what’s left of my hair out over the last day or so. But I have just noticed an interesting, and possibly significant clue: The date and time stamps on the browser displays are about 2 days behind the creation dates of the files on the unix drive!

Here are some screenshots: First, a unix listing of a few files in the folder I want to be able to access via http:  Note that most of the files were created on 1 Feb at 17:14. As of 18:52 on 23 February (my local time), two other files and one directory were created within the last 36 hours.

[Listing 1 from Linux CLI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYTo4.png)

But here is a screen shot of the same folder as seen via a browser window. I am running Apache 2 and I can see these files either by using [https://three-random-words.ngrok-free.app/html/folder_x](https://three-random-words.ngrok-free.app/html/%3Cfolder%3E) or using the same browser pointing to [http://myhostname:80/html/folder_x](http://%3Clocal-host%3E:80/html/%3Cfolder%3E)  In both cases, the three most recently created items are missing.

[Listing 2 from Apache 2 via browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSnLH.png)

As you can see from the server directory listing, all files are owned by root and the permissions are set identically. (Access to the “pico_resources” directory is a bit sloppy but I wondered whether overly restrictive permissions were preventing me from accessing the folder – I cannot see any of the files it contains from the browser.)

But notice also that the files are all dated 3 Feb, 19:05 – more than 2 days after their actual creation times. Is it possible that the missing files will magically appear in the browser window by Sunday afternoon???? I have a sneaking suspicion that Apache won’t allow the files to be displayed because they have creation dates set in what it believes is the future!

Does anyone have any ideas for what is going on here? Is there something obvious that I have missed? (Are there configuration options for Apache that I don’t know about?)

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. I’m a bit confused by what you mean with “Unix drive”. Are the files hosted by Apache located on a network share? Generally, Apache needs files and directories to be owned not by `root` but by `www-data`. This is not a requirement, depending on access permission settings, but generally ideal. If the source files are not in `/var/www`, have you confirmed that AppArmor is not preventing Apache from reading the source directories? 

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1220794 and https://askubuntu.com/a/1501788 are most likely related and can help.

Comment: The website files are most likely all dated the same with no later files present, because that is when they were all copied into a *different directory* to the one you're looking at in the terminal.  Exactly which directory are you looking in there?

Comment: @matigo: Thank you! By "Unix drive" I mean the physical volume on which the source files are stored on my server unit. Apache is running on the same machine so the files are not on a network share. These files are all located in subdirectories of /var/www/html 


I confess I know nothing about AppArmor. I checked out the man page. 

ls -ltr /etc/apparmor.d 


shows several directories were last accessed on 3 February. But I have no clue what I should be looking for to determine whether AppArmor is affecting Apache –from your comment it sounds like it shouldn’t be.

Comment: @guiverc:  Thanks for responding. Here is some info:



Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 23.10
Release: 23.10
Codename: mantic


Server version: Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2024-01-25T06:51:25

Comment: @Raffa  Thanks for those links. I am afraid I don’t think they shed much light. I did find 890886 but this appeared to be resolved by changing the permissions. In my case, permissions and ownership on multiple files in the same directory are identical. But not all of them are visible in the browser.

Comment: @Martin Thornton   The directory I am looking at is the same directory (or at least that’s what I believe!) It is hard to prove this with 100% certainty if a new file is created (or copied into the folder) but it doesn’t appear in the browser!